# browsing #! for non-javascript users

Tags: javascript, ajax

All the links on my site contain `#!` which was [proposed](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) by google for ajax websites.

For an instance for an URL `http://site.com/#!/about` is automatically transformed to `http://site.com/?_escaped_fragment_=about`.

Is there a way for non-javascript to be able to browse these URLs like Google does?

Comment: To use _which_ technique? Javascript?

Comment: The browser does not send the hash fragment with the URL request. If someone who does not have javascript goes to that "page", they just get the home page.

Answer (score 0):

No, afaik. Instead, to have consistent URLs, you might want to get rid of `#!` for those users who have JS — see https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax for example.